# WebGL2 render Uint16Array to canvas as an image

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

I am attempting to render a `Uint16Array` to an image in the browser using webgl2 textures.  I have a working example fiddle of a `Uint8Array` and am struggling with the upgrade to 16bit as webgl has a steep learning curve.

**Working 8-bit fiddle (identical to snippet below):** `Uint8Array` http://jsfiddle.net/njxvftc9/2/ 
**Non-working 16-bit attempt:** `Uint16Array` http://jsfiddle.net/njxvftc9/3/

```js
// image data
var w = 128;
var h = 128;
var size = w * h * 4;
var img = new Uint8Array(size); // need Uint16Array
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i += 4) {
    img[i + 0] = 255; // r
    img[i + 1] = i/64; // g
    img[i + 2] = 0; // b
    img[i + 3] = 255; // a
}

// program
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

var program = gl.createProgram();
//var color_buffer_float_16ui = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float'); // add for 16-bit

// texture
var tex = gl.createTexture(); // create empty texture
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
    0, // mip level
    gl.RGBA, // internal format -> gl.RGBA16UI
    w, h, // width and height
    0, // border
    gl.RGBA, //format -> gm.RGBA_INTEGER
    gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, // type -> gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT
    img // texture data
);

// buffer
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var bufferData =  new Float32Array([
    -1, -1,
    1, -1,
    1, 1,               
    1, 1,
    -1, 1,
    -1, -1
]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// shaders
program.vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(program.vs,
                "attribute vec4 vertex;\n" + // incoming pixel input?
                "varying vec2 pixelCoordinate;\n" + // variable used to pass position to fragment shader
                "void main(){\n" +
                " gl_Position = vertex;\n" + // set pixel output position to incoming position (pass through)
                " pixelCoordinate = vertex.xy*0.5+0.5;\n" + // set coordinate for fragment shader
                "}\n");

program.fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(program.fs,
                "precision highp float;\n" + // ?
                "uniform sampler2D tex;\n" + // ?
                "varying vec2 pixelCoordinate;\n" + // receive pixel position from vertex shader
                "void main(){\n" +
                " gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, pixelCoordinate);\n" + // lookup color in texture image at coordinate position and set color to
                "}\n");

gl.compileShader(program.vs);
gl.compileShader(program.fs);

gl.attachShader(program,program.vs);
gl.attachShader(program,program.fs);

gl.deleteShader(program.vs);
gl.deleteShader(program.fs);

// program
gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertex");
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // execute program
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

I have tried made many other techniques, referenced the spec, tried converting to floating point in the shaders, and have tried to combine methods seen here: [Render to 16bits unsigned integer 2D texture in WebGL2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101023/render-to-16bits-unsigned-integer-2d-texture-in-webgl2) with no success.

I prefer vanilla js but am open to using libraries such as twgl or three.js as long as the input is a `Uint16Array`, the shaders can output any format (float, etc).

Can anyone with more experience in webgl2 point me in the right direction or provide a working sample fiddle here?  Is there a simple mistake in my code, am I missing a larger concept, is this even possible?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have been looking this, and have made some good progress.  After considering the link regarding snippets, I may hold off answering until it is made into a snippet.

Comment: @gman thanks for the snippet recommendation - I wasn't aware of them!  I added a snippet as per your request.  Do you have any thoughts on the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to put 16bit data into a texture you need to choose a 16bit texture internal format. Looking at [the list of internal formats](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-data-textures.html) your choices for RGBA are

```
gl.RGBA16I    // 16bit integers
gl.RGBA16UI   // 16bit unsigned integers
gl.RGBA16F    // 16bit half floats
```

It looks like you choose `gl.RGBA16UI`

To access that texture in the shader this line

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
```

has to change this this

```
uniform usampler2D tex;
```

That syntax is only available with GLSL 3.00 es so you need to add `#version 300 es` to the top of both shaders.

Switching to `#version 300 es` also means [other syntax changes](https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl1-to-webgl2.html). `attribute` becomes `in`, `varying` becomes `out` in a vertex shader and `in` in a fragment shader. `gl_FragColor` disappears and you have to declare your own output for example `out vec4 fooColor;`. Also `texture2D` becomes just `texture`

You can not using filtering on integer textures so these 2 lines

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);
```

need to change to

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

And when you get data out of the texture it will be unsigned integers so this line

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex, pixelCoordinate);
```

would end up changing to something like

```
out vec4 fooColor;  // named this fooColor to make it clear you pick the name

void main() {
  uvec4 unsignedIntValues = texture(tex, pixelCoordinate);
  vec4 floatValues0To65535 = vec4(unsignedIntValues);  
  vec4 colorValues0To1 = floatValues0To65535 / 65535.0;
  fooColor = colorValues0To1;
}
```

Of course you can shorten that math to a single line

```
  fooColor = vec4(texture(tex, pixelCoordinate)) / 65535.0;
```

Example:

```js
// image data
var w = 128;
var h = 128;
var size = w * h * 4;
var img = new Uint16Array(size); // need Uint16Array
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i += 4) {
    img[i + 0] = 65535; // r
    img[i + 1] = i/64 * 256; // g
    img[i + 2] = 0; // b
    img[i + 3] = 65535; // a
}

// program
var canvas = document.getElementById('cv');
var gl = canvas.getContext('webgl2');

var program = gl.createProgram();
//var color_buffer_float_16ui = gl.getExtension('EXT_color_buffer_float'); // add for 16-bit

// texture
var tex = gl.createTexture(); // create empty texture
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texImage2D(
    gl.TEXTURE_2D, // target
    0, // mip level
    gl.RGBA16UI, // internal format -> gl.RGBA16UI
    w, h, // width and height
    0, // border
    gl.RGBA_INTEGER, //format -> gm.RGBA_INTEGER
    gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, // type -> gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT
    img // texture data
);

// buffer
var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
var bufferData =  new Float32Array([
    -1, -1,
    1, -1,
    1, 1,               
    1, 1,
    -1, 1,
    -1, -1
]);
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferData, gl.STATIC_DRAW);

// shaders
program.vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(program.vs, `#version 300 es
  in vec4 vertex; // incoming pixel input?
  out vec2 pixelCoordinate; // variable used to pass position to fragment shader
  void main(){
     gl_Position = vertex;  // set pixel output position to incoming position (pass through)
     pixelCoordinate = vertex.xy*0.5+0.5; // set coordinate for fragment shader
  }
`);

program.fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
gl.shaderSource(program.fs, `#version 300 es
  precision highp float; // ?
  uniform highp usampler2D tex; // ?
  in vec2 pixelCoordinate; // receive pixel position from vertex shader
  out vec4 fooColor;
  void main() {
     uvec4 unsignedIntValues = texture(tex, pixelCoordinate);
     vec4 floatValues0To65535 = vec4(unsignedIntValues);
     vec4 colorValues0To1 = floatValues0To65535 / 65535.0;
     fooColor = colorValues0To1;
  }
`);

gl.compileShader(program.vs);
checkCompileError(program.vs);
gl.compileShader(program.fs);
checkCompileError(program.fs);

function checkCompileError(s) {
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(s, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
   console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(s));
  }
}

gl.attachShader(program,program.vs);
gl.attachShader(program,program.fs);

gl.deleteShader(program.vs);
gl.deleteShader(program.fs);

// program
gl.bindAttribLocation(program, 0, "vertex");
gl.linkProgram(program);
gl.useProgram(program);
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(0);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(0, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6); // execute program
```

```html
<canvas id="cv" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
```

Comment: One thing that helps me (and apparently you, based on your code) with these kind of questions is checking for compiler errors.  Just thought this would be a good thing to point out as it is a very useful debugging technique.

Comment: The code changes you mentioned in the answer were all correct, but your snippet still doesn't work quite right.  You need to set `img[i + 1] = i*4;` and `img[i + 3] = 65535;` in the for loop.

Comment: strange, I originally had those changes but must not have picked "save". Thanks for pointing it out. As for checking for compiler errors I agree 100%. I just assume the questioner was going for a *minimal* example though if it was me I'd have left the checking in (like I did above)

Comment: @gman Thank you, I am blown away by the level of detail in your answer - tremendously helpful from a learning perspective.  This really clears up my confusion between v1 and v2 shader syntax and I would never have caught these compatibility issues on my own.  Thanks again!

Comment: @FEA5T, you might have gotten clues by checking the JavaScript console. It should have at least told you your texture was not usable. Running your snippet with just the texture changed tells you about the NEAREST issue. Fixing that gets an error about samplers not matching (sampler2D vs usampler2D) so you'd at least have gotten some clues where to look.

Comment: @gman I was on top of the console but didn't know to log compile errors.  One of the things that has made webgl difficult is the lack of debugging capability.  For example, now I am trying to move from RGBA16UI to R16UI and I can't find any information about what 4 points are contained in a uvec4 texture(...) lookup call.  Do you know why a uvec4 would be returned on a single channel lookup call?

Comment: The hint is the R in R16UI. The data is in the `r` channel as in `float data = texture(someSampler, someTexcoords).r;` The other 3 channels, g, b, a, are either undefined or 0 or 1 (don't remember of the top of my head). Regardless the R stands for RED. You might find [these tutorials](https://webgl2fundamentals.org) helpful

Comment: @gman Would you recommend using a webgl2d library like [PixiJS](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi.js) or just working with the 'native' code as you have here?

Comment: @gman What does the following line actually do?  
pixelCoordinate = vertex.xy*0.5+0.5;

Comment: @A.Mort it's generating a texture coordinate from the position data. This only works because we know the position data is a quad that goes from -1 to 1 in each direction so * 0.5 + 0.5 makes the values go from 0 to 1 which is what we need reference the texture to draw an image. In the general case you'd provide texture coordinates as a separate attribute but for this particular case they are not needed.